# Setting container height based on container width and multiply by a constant

Tags: jquery, css, height, width, equation

I am attempting to set the height of a container based on its width multiplied by .75.

I've come up with this but not sure where I've gone wrong because it doesn't work:

```
$('#slideContent').load(function() {
            var wide = ('#slideContent').width()
          $(this).css('height', $(this).width( wide * 0.75 ));
        });
```

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot the $ on your selector for `#slideContent`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this now.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                var wide = $('#slideContent').css('width');
                var calculate = parseInt(wide, 10)* 0.75;

                $('#slideContent').css('height', calculate);
            });
```

First i take the width of the element and store it in "wide" variable.
Secondly i make a calculation variable. When asking for a width or height from a CSS styled element you will have a value returned as a string containing "px", to filter off this "px" and make it an integer i use the "parseInt()" function. The ", 10" makes sure it's a radix 10 number.
The rest should make sense pretty much by itself i believe.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to change the height, why just not use `$(this).height(modWidth)`, where `var modWidth = wide * 0.75` to change the height?